# sqlalchemy update value via resultproxy-object

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a large table with a lot of textual data. The code snippet below is a minimal example from a larger `textcorpus-reader` that i am writing at the moment.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///corpus.db")
meta = MetaData(bind=engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=False, expire_on_commit=False, autocommit=False)

data_table = Table("data", meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)


def computationally_heavy(raw_text):
    """
    This does a lot of text-processing and needs a lot of RAM and CPU.
    For the sake of this example it does just this:
    """
    return raw_text.split("\n")


session = Session()
query = session.query(data_table).yield_every(10)

for i, row in enumerate(query):
    result = computationally_heavy(row.raw_text)

    # This is, what is not working - column 'processed_text' does already exist:
    row.processed_text = result

    if i % 250 == 0:
        s.flush()

session.commit()
session.close()
```

My problem is that i would like to update single rows in the `for` loop, but i get:

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute.
```

I read that this way of assigning to rows was possible in `sqlalchemy` versions prior to 0.9 or something. (I have 1.2.0, but downgrading seems like a silly option, since there must be a way to do this.)

And i know this way of assigning to single rows based on query results is possible in `sqlsoup`, but would rather not use another package, since there sure is a way to do this from `sqlalchemy`.

My question:

**How do i have to do the `row.processed_text = result` to get the desired update of the single row going?**

Since this is supposed to work with different databases, where the column may be named differently i would like to avoid a hardcoded `Query(data_table).where(data_table.primary_key == row.primary_key).update()` because i do not necessarily know the name of the primary key column.

PS.: Performance of the database is not the focus here, since i have time, this is only supposed to run very rarely and the `computationally_heavy()` consumes a lot of time anyway.

Also i am social scientist, not a programmer, so sorry, if this is a really dumb question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you've mixed [Core](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/) and the [ORM](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/). Model instances track changes to attributes through [instrumentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/glossary.html#term-instrumentation). Instead of just a `Table` define a Declarative class, using your table:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base(metadata=meta)

class DataTable(Base):
    __table__ = Table("data", meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

Use that in your query and the resulting model objects will track changes to their attributes:

```
query = session.query(DataTable).yield_every(10)
```

> I read that this way of assigning to rows was possible in sqlalchemy versions prior to 0.9 or something. (I have 1.2.0, but downgrading seems like a silly option, since there must be a way to do this.)

That the result tuples were assignable was due to an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3420) and [was fixed in version 1.0.5](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/changelog/changelog_10.html#change-8dff32ea855329842148a57ea75d4663). It did not mean that they tracked changes in the same fashion as the ORM does.